# why C++17 destroy()/destroy_n() functions run forward (and not backwards)?

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++17 the `destroy()` and `destroy_n()` run the destructor of a range of objects.

However according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy) this is done in a forward manner, i.e.,

```
template< class ForwardIt >
void destroy( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last )
{
  for (; first != last; ++first)
    std::destroy_at(std::addressof(*first));
}
```

But destruction of an array is [reverse to the order of construction](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#order-dtors-for-arrays) as required by the standard.

So what would be the use-case of `destroy()` and `destroy_n()`?

Is there a reason for not being consistent with normal array destruction, or is this a mistake in cppreference?

Comment: Just a guess: because then it can be implemented using `operator++` on the iterator instead of `operator--`.

Comment: The `ExecutionPolicy` overload implies destruction order is allowed to not matter.

Comment: In general, objects created explicitly by user code can be explicitly destroyed in whatever order the user want. I don't see the relevance of the array destruction.

Comment: @Caleth: right. Thanks for pointing this out. So it is the parallelism that makes one to give up the order guarantee.

Comment: It’s because **forward** iterators don’t go backwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `destroy()`/`destroy_n()` is consistent - but with the standard algorithms. It would bring a lot of unncecessary confusion to add a single algorithm that works backwards. Apart from that, You can always do:

```
destroy(std::rbegin(array), std::rend(array));
```

which does exactly what You want and expect while maintaining the style and type requirements of the rest of the algorithms.

One more thing concerning the standard. It only states that the C-style array works this way. There is nothing about `vector`, `map` or any other stl container. As `destroy` function can take any C++ range it is reasonable that it behaves as typical C++ code, not as part of the syntax that is inherited quite long ago.

Comment: I see. So the reverse destruction order guarantee was dropped by the standard containers. Although the reason for that is not immediately clear to me, but I think this fact answers the question pretty much. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This functions require forward iterator which can only be moved forward.

There does not seem to be a requirement for specific order of destruction. With different execution policies the order can be different.

You can pass reverse iterators there if you have at least bidirectional iterators.